# How can the increments of a CIR process be derived?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

For a CIR process, which has SDE
$$
dr_t = \alpha (\mu - r_t) dt + \sigma \sqrt{r_t} dW_t
$$
how can I derive the increments over the discrete time-interval from $r_t$ to $r_{t+1}$?

Comment: $dr_t$ is replaced by $\Delta r_t$, $dt$ is replaced by $\Delta t$ and $dW_t$ is replaced by $\xi_i \sqrt{\Delta t}$ where $\xi_i$ is random $N(0,1)$

Comment: An alternative, "exact" simulation would be via the non-central Chi-Squared distribution, for example explained here: https://www.deriscope.com/docs/Andersen_Jaeckel_Kahl_2010.pdf

Comment: And of course https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57790/cox-ingersoll-ross-monte-carlo-simulation and https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8114/monte-carlo-simulating-cox-ingersoll-ross-process

Comment: @noob2, would you be able to explain why that is the case?

Comment: It is the Euler Maruyama method, the simplest (but not the only, as Kermitfrog pointed out) way to simulate an SDE in discrete time. $dW_t$ is random zero-mean and has a variance proportional to $dt$, so the standard deviation is proportional to $\sqrt{dt}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not totally sure I understand what you want to achieve. It seems like you are interested in discretizing CIR SDE. This can be done using the Euler-Murayama scheme for an equidistant decomposition of the time interval $[0, T]$, $\{0=t_0<\dots<t_n=T\}$.

First of all, let us write the model dynamics:
$$r_t=r_0+\alpha\int_0^t(\mu-r_s)ds+\sigma\int_0^t\sqrt{r_s}dW_s$$

We need to discretize this process:
$$r_{t+\Delta t}=r_t+\alpha(\mu-r_t)\Delta t+\sigma\sqrt{r_t}W_{\Delta t}$$
with $\Delta t=\frac{T}{n}$ and $W_{\Delta t}\sim\mathcal N\left(0,\frac{T}{n}\right)\Rightarrow W_{\Delta t}=\sqrt{\frac{T}{n}}\varepsilon,$ with $\varepsilon$ being a standard normal random variable.

Finally, we can use the trapezoidal rule to numerically integrate the simulated CIR rates and compute what you need (for example, the Monte Carlo zero-coupon bond prices).